# iphone is there a way to create a view over the tabbar?

Tags: iphone

I have an application that pulls up a login page when it first starts. This login page goes over the application and does not let anyone through until they've logged in. I also have a settings tab on my main application that needs to lead back to this login screen. Right now it displays the login screen with the tab bar over it. Is there a way to get the login view over the tab bar?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar by having views transitioning in over the top of my tab bar. I used yourView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; with a 'close' button to let users return to the tab bar screen. I've not done this so it automatically comes in on app fire-up but instead call the view from a button on the screen separate to the tab bar controls. However, I'm sure you'll be able to utilise this somehow to do what you want.

In fact I've actually used this way of calling up views all over my app, each time it covers the tababr and you have to 'close' it to get back to main tabbed navigation you came from.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting below in your viewDidLoad of login screen:

```
self.tabBarController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Comment: that didn't do anything for me

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a subclass of UITabBarController, which then performs various checks in `viewDidAppear:`. The login view is modally presented, as @Maxwell suggested.

```
// a subclass of UITabBarController

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  [self firstLoadChecks];
}

- (void) firstLoadChecks
{
  if (!self.hasLogin) {
    id login = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self autorelease];
    id nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:login] autorelease];
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet;
    nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
  }
}

// from LoginViewControllerDelegate
- (void) didLogin
{
  self.hasLogin = YES;
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// my LoginViewController can be closed without a login
- (void) dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) animated
{
  [super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];

  [self firstLoadChecks];
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working correctly with mine but I came up with what might be a better solution. I figured out how to dim and disable the other tabs when someone attempts to change the settings info and it stays that way until valid info is submitted.